# Vite: process CSS after JS is tree-shaken

Tags: vite, rollup, postcss

I want to run purgeCSS on my CSS, by looking at my .js code to see which selectors are used, but that will only be useful once all dead code was eliminated.

How do I hook into the build so that after the js bundles are written, the .css files can be altered by purgeCSS?

Will that still allow naming the files after their content hash?